# Playing audio files on a website

Tags: audio, html5-audio

Can you suggest a good way to play audio files on a website?

Comment: Of course, if you are going to use `<audio>` you'd still have to be careful about codec support. Oh, and fallback. Definitely fallback. Try modernizr.

Answer (score 2):

I am building a browser based sound board with html5 audio and java script. I am testing it in Safari, chrome, ie and firefox. So far no problem. The only issue is the formats the browsers play ie firefox will only play .ogg.

To solve this i have a user agent detector to direct to a version of the site with has .ogg files on it.

I would recommend using the audio tag. As for fall back 'Yi Jiang' is dead right. You could use something like JPlayer which is an html5 audio plugin with fallback.

-kev

Please mark an answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a [HTML5 Audio Google Search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=html5+audio)?

```
<audio src="elvis.ogg" controls autobuffer></audio>
```

Comment: I'm aware of it but they said that it is not fully supported yet so it is not recommented...is that still true or things have changed?

Comment: what target audience / browsers are you supporting?